# Is Shmitat Ksafim practiced after a Yovel?

Tags: halacha, money, shmita

Many link between the Yovel and Shmitat Ksafim, like in [Shu"A H"M 67](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.67?lang=bi):

> "**דין שמיטה ופרוזבול ובו ל"ח סעיפים:**
>   אין שמיטת כספים נוהגת מן התורה אלא בזמן שהיובל נוהג"

Is Shmitat Kasafim actually practiced after the 50th year, in other words after the 49th (regular Shmita) AND 50th (Yovel) year?

Answer (score 3):

[Rambam Hilchot Shemitah v’Yovel 10:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbatical_Year_and_the_Jubilee.10.16?lang=bi) writes that *shemitat kesafim* only applies in a *shemitah* year, not in *yovel*.

Comment: I researched it a bit and found a deeper understanding here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96464/15579

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer seem to be more interesting that Joel's finding alone.

THe question strongly implies that there's a connection between Yovel and Shmitat Ksafim (SK), however, none of the interpreters (besides Tumim on H"M) research the reason.

As Joel mentioned Rambam and others hold that SK is not practiced on Yovel, however Yerushalmi R"H 17 presents [seemingly] that SK IS practiced on Yovel as it is practiced on a Shmitah year:

> קידוש ב"ד ותקיעת שופר והשמטת כספים מעכבים היובל.

As Kurban Haeda understood it:

> משמע לפי מה שהבין בקרבן עדה שם שכמו שיש דין שמיטת כספים בשביעית כך יש ביובל וזה מעכב את היובל.

R' Moshe Luriah in Beyt G'nozay reconciles them both in a simple way:

> "והנה לפי מה שמשמע בירושלמי שהבאנו כפשוטו שזה משמט הרי ניחא שמכאן המקור שלא כהספרי שמשמע שיובל אינו משמט, ולפי מה שהרמב"ם למד בהיקש בגמרא ששמיטת כספים תלוי' ביובל בהכרח לומר שגם היובל משמט כמבואר.
>
> אלא שא"כ קשה הרי הרמב"ם כתב לא כן שרק שביעית משמטת ולא היובל ובהכרח לבאר הירושלמי כמו שביארנו קודם שאין ביובל דין שמיטת כספים ותקשה לדברינו למה לא תהא כהנת כפונדקית. אכן נראה שכלל לא שייך ענין שמיטת כספים ביובל. **שהרי כל דיני היובל הם בתחילתו שמיד שנכנס יובל הוא משחרר השדות**...
>
> וא"כ הרי אין שום מציאות של שמיטת כספים ביובל. **שהרי סוף שביעית משמט ממש בסוף היום ושמיטת יובל צריכה להתחיל בתחילת השנה ואין ביניהם אפילו כמלא נימא זה יוצא וזה נכנס** ולא שייך אז היכי תמצא של חוב מחודש שהיובל צריך להשמיטו."

Free translation: "*because SK of A Shmitah year happens AFTER the year ends, on the first day of the next year which is Yovel, and the freedoms of Yovel (like return of the land and freeing the slaves) happens in the beginning of the Yovel year turns out they are the same moment, the SK of the Shmitah IS the SK of Yovel*."

Comment: Doesn't the Rosh hold Shmita is Meshammeit at the beginning? Why wouldn't Yovel be Meshammeit only on Yom Kippur?

Comment: @DoubleAA Another interesting question.